# Get PDF be written in the center of the page itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I had a fillable PDF document (2 pages in total) consisting of different sizes of page; the first page is 8.5 * 11 inches (612 * 792), containing fillable fields; the second page is 9.5 * 12 inches (684 * 864), containing No fillable fields. Even though the second page is larger, the margin of it can be ignored. In other word, if get the second page printed as A4, no content would be cut.

However, when I am doing the document concatenation(using 612 *792), all second pages will be lined up at the left bottom corner of the page, making partial contents lost on top and right margin of the page. Even though full content can be fit in when (684 *864) is applied, all first pages are lined up at the left bottom corner of the page as well, making it a wide blank margins on top and right of page.

Is there anyway that I can get pages be written in center of page all the times so that I can use size of 612* 792 without losing contents in second pages?

Below is the concatenation method:

```
private static byte[] ConcatContents(List<byte[]> pdf)
{
    byte[] all;

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Document doc = new Document(new Rectangle(612, 792));

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);

        doc.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        PdfImportedPage page;

        PdfReader reader;
        foreach (byte[] p in pdf)
        {
            reader = new PdfReader(p);
            int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;

            // loop over document pages
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
               doc.NewPage();
               page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
               cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        doc.Close();

        all = ms.ToArray();

        ms.Flush();
        ms.Dispose();
   }
   return all;
}
```

[UPDATE]

Original Page Size difference in PDF
[image]

After Page concatenation, some of the content lost because it seems like PDF was generated from left bottom corner up. The page size difference causes the lost of page content. As you can see in the picture below, the first line of second page content

> "BECUASE THIS FORM IS USED BY VARIOUS GOVERNMENT..."

was cut off, as well as some content in the right.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean by "lining up". How pages are displayed in relation to each other has more to do with the viewing application and not the page content. For what it's worth, it wasn't until Acrobat 2 when there was support for continuous/toilet paper page display.

Comment: @plinth Please let me know if the "update" part make any sense to you

Comment: OK - so you're trying to stamp the content of any arbitrary page onto a new page of a given size. That means you need to know the bounds of the old page and set a transform that places its content in a different place on the new page.  It's basically a translation which will be (.5dx,.5dy) where dx and dy are the deltas from old page width/height and new page width/height, but this will not guarantee that all content will fit.

Comment: If your goal is "produce a document with pages all the same size", this is a decent enough solution. If your goal is concatenate two documents, this is suboptimal.

Comment: @plinth *suboptimal* - a very decent way to put it. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Thanks to plinth's suggestions, I found out that the below code work perfectly to adjust all the second pages to center of the page. Although it doesn't look like a good practice, it works eventually.

```
// loop over document pages
for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
{
    doc.NewPage();
    page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

    if (i == 1)
    {
        cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        float page1Height, page1Width, page2Height, page2Width;
        page1Height = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i - 1).Height;
        page1Width = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i - 1).Width;
        page2Height = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Height;
        page2Width = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i).Width;
        cb.AddTemplate(page, (page1Width - page2Width) / 2, (page1Height - page2Height) / 2);
    }
}
```

Here is the displayed result
[image]

Comment: For a general solution one should calculate those numbers as indicated by @plinth as the half differences of width and height of the crop boxes involved.